# Find, count and extract duplications in dataframes in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe includes two columns [Color, Value] as shown in the figure below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Color":[Green, Blue, Green, Green, Blue, Red, Green, Green, Blue, Red, Green, Green, Blue, Red, Blue, Blue, Green], 
                "Value":[20, 21, 25, 30, 41, 512, 40, 41, 352, 31, 52, 451, 253, 54, 142, 122, 784 ]})
```

[image]

The aim is to find a list of duplications of color's column and count them. I used this code:

```
dups_colors = pd.concat(g for _, g in data.groupby("Color") if len(g) > 1)#find duplications
```

The output is:

[image]

Then, I counted the duplications using this code:

```
count = dups_colors.pivot_table(index=['Color'], aggfunc='size')#count number of duplications
```

The output is:

[image]

Until here everything is fine. Now I have two questions as follows:

Q1: I need to add the count column into the dups_colors dataframe in this mannar.

[image]

Q2: I need to extract the values correspond to each color into a sperate column with header of the color, same like this:

[image]

Please have a look and help me.

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but I won't type in the pictures. Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: Question 2 is pivot table. Search SO for *How to pivot a dataframe*

Comment: @timgeb I updated the question such that you can use the test sample of data. Could you help?

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you help with Q1 first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Q1 I would do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':['Green','Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Red']})
count = {'Green':3, 'Blue':2}
df['Count'] = None
for name, occur in df.groupby('color').indices.items():
    df['Count'][occur[0]] = count.get(name)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  color Count
0  Green     3
1  Green  None
2  Green  None
3   Blue     2
4   Blue  None
5    Red  None
```

Note: I simplified your example and decided to use `None` for all non-first occurences of given `color` and single `color`s.

Comment: Your answer seems logical, but when tried it I got all Count column values are None!!. I got this Warning:

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count duplicates, I would suggest using `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated()`:

```
df['dupl'] = df.duplicated('Color', False)
```

Where the `False` parameter counts all duplicated values as per the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

If you want to add a new column showing how many duplicates that row has, you can use:

```
df['duplicated_count'] = df.groupby('Color').dupl.transform('sum')
```

At last, you can reshape the dataframe as follows, although this is not quite what you expect:

```
df.pivot(columns='Color', values='Value').fillna(0)
```

I should say that all columns in a data frame should have the same length, so the result in Q2 is not achievable as it looks in Excel.